# How to make a short horizontal line over an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a short horizontal line over an image. Like a quote followed by horizontal line followed by author name. An example of what I'm trying to do is below.

[image: Quote with line separating author name]

How can I achieve this in html css?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In the case of your question there are some specifics you could add that would greatly help in narrowing down a specific answer. Tell us more about the requirements as the question is very broad right now, are the images all the same size, is the text part of the image, or is it overlayed on the image, is the text fixed, or does it come from a database or backend?

Comment: There is only one image in the background and there is text over it. I want to draw a horizontal line as shown in the image I attached. I think that is very specific and has attracted three answers before your comment and all answer meet the purpose of the question. Text if fixed. I clearly mention I want to draw a horizontal line over an image. Text is over the image. Text is a quotation with quote and author name separated by a horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either an hr or a div with a border. I made a simple example, hope it helps.

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%
}

body{
 background: lightslategray;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;
}

.quote {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/600/200/abstract/?random=true');
  color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <h1>A dream doesn't become reality through magic<br/> it takes sweat, determination and hard work.</h1>
  <hr />
  <h2>Colin Powell</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the horizontal line in html `<hr>`

Comment: I tried but its not working over the image. The image is in the background and over this we have to draw a short horizontal line. May be I am making a mistake.

Comment: add a lower z-index on your background. Can you post it on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: I am trying to share my code with codepen but I am not able to share the image in codepen. Can you suggest how I can share background image in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several way. How you go about it will depend on what you are trying to accomplish. Here are two ways; one using `br` element and the other using a `div` (it could be a label too). If you want to use a different color and add more style to it, you want to go with the `div`

```css
.motto, .author{
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .motto{
      font-size: 1.85em;
    }
    .br{
      width: 50%;
      height: 2px;
      margin: 25px auto;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background-color: #0088ee;
    }
```

```html
<i class="motto">It is better to be feared than loved if you cannot be both</i>

<div class="br"></div>
<!-- <hr/> -->

<strong class="author">Niccolo Machiavelli</strong>
```

Comment out `<div class="br"></div>` and uncomment `<hr/>` to see the two results.